# segmentation fault while assigning string

Tags: c++, c

```
void getAgentInfo( char** agent_address )
{
    #define MAX_IP_SIZE 100
    FILE *fcfg=NULL;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char *p , *pend;
    int findlen_ips, findlen_num;
    findlen_ips = strlen (findkey_ips);
    findlen_num = strlen (findkey_num);
    int iCount = 1; //in agent array entry
    fcfg = fopen (FCFG, "r");

    while (p = fgets (line, MAXLINE, fcfg))
    {
        //printf ("Looking at %s\n", p);
        if (p = findval (line, findkey_num, findlen_num))
        {
            pend = p + strlen (p) - 1;  /* check last char for newline terminator */
            if (*pend == '\n')
                *pend = 0;
            printf ("%s\n", p); /* process/parse the value */
            NumOfIp = atoi(p);
            //agent_address = (char*)calloc(NumOfIp + 1, sizeof(char));
            agent_address = new char*[NumOfIp + 1];
            for(int icount = 0; icount < NumOfIp+1; icount++)
            {
                agent_address[icount] = new char[MAX_IP_SIZE];
            }
        }

        if (p = findval (line, findkey_ips, findlen_ips))
        {
            pend = p + strlen (p) - 1;  /* check last char for newline terminator */
            if (*pend == '\n')
                *pend = 0;
            printf ("addr = %s\n", p); /* process/parse the value */
            agent_address[iCount]= p; //strcpy(agent_address[iCount], p)
            //printf("agent_address[iCount++]=%s\n",agent_address[iCount]);
            iCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

From above code I'm reading a txt file and getting values in a int var and depending on that value craeting 2d string array to store values:

...
        char** agent_address = NULL;
        getAgentInfo(agent_address);
        TRACE_STR("\n");
        agent_address[0] = MasterCPMAddr;
....

I am succesfully getting string from line `agent_address[0] = MasterCPMAddr;` but afer that when I am storing it I am getting segmentation fault; //tried with `strcpy(agent_address[0], MasterCPMAddr)` also

Comment: perhaps you are trying to push char string to unallocatedd memory location.

Comment: After your call to `getAgentInfo`, `agent_address` is still `NULL`, because the double pointer is passed by value. When you allocate memory for `agent address`, you must either pass it by reference (which will make it a triple pointer in `getAgentInfo`) or, possibly more elegantly, return it from `getAgentInfo`. Whether you should assign a string literal or copy chars with `strcpy` depends on your data structure.

Comment: You clearly are using a C++ compiler, perhaps consider using C++ features that make life easier (ie: vector, string, pass-by-reference...) see my answer for details

Comment: I fixed it by using Reference...thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*note*
Your code seems to be C, with a light sprinkling of C++. I would recommend you choose a side. Either write in C, or C++. The latter offers a robust library that handles the nitty-gritty of file IO and memory management for you. Passing a `std::vector<std::string>` to your function would make sense here. A more C++ style to tackle your problem would be this:

```
int read_lines(std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    int count_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);//add line to vector
        ++count_lines;
    }
    return count_lines;
}
```

A full, tested and working example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;//to get rid of that pesky std::

int read_lines(vector<string>& lines)
{
    int count_lines = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream infile("file.txt");
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);//add line to vector
        ++count_lines;
    }
    return count_lines;
}

int main ( void )
{
    vector<string> list;
    int lines_read = read_lines(list);
    int i=1;
    cout << "Read " << lines_read << " lines" << endl;
    //from start to finish
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        cout << "Line: " << i++ << " "<< *it << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to do this the old-fashioned C-way, then here's my answer to your problem:

You have undefined behaviour. Inside the `getAgentInfo` function, you have a pointer to a string (`p` and `pend`). These pointers, though, are only valid within the function. You have to copy the actual string to the `agent_address` variable (using `strcpy` or `strncpy`).
Make sure you allocate the memory required to store that string, and show us how you are passing the variable to. A pure C function that assigns a number of strings to an array of char pointers could look something like this:

```
int read_lines(char *store_lines[], size_t max_lines)
{
    int i=0;
    size_t len;
    char buffer[200];//temp buffer
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)|
        return -1;//error
    while (i < max_lines && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL)
    {//read lines while we haven't reached the max, and there are lines to read
        len = strlen(buffer);
        store_lines[i] = malloc(len+1);//allocate memory
        if (store_lines[i] == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);//ALWAYS fclose
            return 0;//failed to allocate enough memory
        }
        *store_lines[i] = '\0';//set to empty
        strncat(store_lines[i], buffer, len);
        ++i;//next line
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;//return number of lines read
}
```

You can call this function with an array of pointers like so:

```
char *data[10];
int check = read_lines(data, 10);
if (check == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file");
    exit(1);
}
if (check == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory\n");
    for (int i=0;data[i] != NULL;++i)
        fprintf(stderr, "Read line %d: %s\n", i+1, data[i]);//allocated memory vs null-pointers, possible to free memory here
    exit(1);
}
printf("Read %d lines out of %d\n", check, sizeof data/sizeof *data);
for (int i=0;i<check;++i)
{
    printf("Line %d: %s\n", i+1, data[i]);
    free(data[i]);
    data[i] = NULL;
}
return 0;
```

If you want the `read_lines` function to allocate the array itself, too, you'll have to pass the address of a pointer to a pointer (three levels of indirection). But for your own sake, and that of those you love, avoid whenever possible:

```
int read_lines(char ***store_lines)
{
    char buffer[200],
        **target = *store_lines;//makes it easier
    size_t len, i;
    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp))
    {
        len = strlen(buffer);
        realloc(target, (1+i)*sizeof *target);//re-allocate memory for pointer array
        if (target == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        target[i] = malloc(len+1);//allocate space for chars
        if (target[i] == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
        *target[i] = '\0';//empty string, enable strncat use
        strncat(target[i], buffer, len);
        ++i;//next line
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return (int) i;//cast to int - optional
}
```

You can call this function like so:

```
char **data = NULL;
int lines_read = read_lines(&data);
if (lines_read == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (lines_read == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough RAM");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (int i=0;i<lines_read;++i)
    printf("%d) %s\n", i, data[i]);//print out line-by-line
//free memory
```

Answer (score 1):

in c, arguments are passed by value. so to pass `agent_address` to your function you need declare it like:

```
void getAgentInfo(char*** agent_address )
{
```

and then dereference `agent_address` inside a function.
for now, `agent_address` in your function is just a local variable.

Comment: `int &NumOfIp` won't work in C. Passing by reference is a C++ thing

Comment: that's right. my answer concerns only C, however, OP mixes in his code C with C++.

Comment: indeed he is... I just noticed the `new char *` bit, too. OP really ought to choose, and perhaps consider using the `std::string` class

Comment: i would change ``new`` to ``malloc/free`` and then code would be a pure C code. **EDIT** : there is an integer declaration inside a for loop, so i am not right with previous statement :)

Comment: declaring an int in a loop is perfectly valid in C, too, C99 and C11 support this, but it may require a compiler flag to be set (`-std=c99` for gcc)

Comment: thank you Elias. when i write C code, i am used to declare variable used in loop earlier. so, all in all, my statement finally was correct!